# Cant get the correct value of ASCII using getchar()

Tags: c

It's probably a simple correction since the program is super short but please help me understand why am i getting weird output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    char x;
    printf("please enter a word, and ctrl + d to see the resault\n");

    while ((x = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%d", x);
    }


    return 0;
}

intput: 'd'
output: 10010
```

Comment: is it something with the EOF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get 10010 is because you are pressing 'd' followed by 'return'.

Change your printf format to "%d\n" to visualize this more easily.

A fix could be:

```
while ((x = getchar()) != '\n' )
{
}
```

Comment: right, it fixed the problem. now i just need to add specification for the newline since its printing 10 also under the value of the character. thanks! @user876651

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're truncating the return value.

`getchar()` returns `int`, look at [any documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar).

It has to be this way, since `EOF` can't be allowed to "collide" with any character. Since `int` is larger than `char`,  this allows `EOF` to be somewhere inside the space of numbers expressible as `int`, while being *outside* the set of `char`.

As explained by user876651, the output "10010" is in fact two decimal integers that are printed next to each other:

- 100 is the ASCII code for the lower-case letter `'d'`
- 10 is ASCII for the linefeed `'\n'`

You should print with a newline: `printf("%d\n", x);` to get these on lines of their own.

Comment: If you try running the code you will see that this isn't what the user is experiencing as a problem. The output is 10010 as they are catching the return key (ascii 10) as input

Answer (score 1):

Change `char x` to `int x` as `getchar()` returns `int` and that is what you are trying to print.

edit:

`getchar()` to work, you need to press enter i.e. `\n` which will also get printed.